# Attach metadata to Stripe Checkout Subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments, metadata

I'm trying to use Stripe Checkout for a subscription service.

Using the PHP SDK

```
Session::create([
            'customer' => $user->stripeCustomerId,
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
                'price' => 'price_0MACBYAGG6RS7KP5c1fNa6v9',
                'quantity' => $amount,
            ]],
            'subscription_data' => [
                'metadata' => [
                    'message' => $message,
                ],
            ],
            'mode' => 'subscription',
            'success_url' => UrlHelper::url('?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'),
            'cancel_url' => UrlHelper::url('?cancel=true'),
        ]);
```

but metadata is never attached as per the docs https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-metadata-with-checkout-sessions?locale=en-GB

I have a single charge option that passes:

```
'payment_intent_data' => [
                'metadata' => [
                    'message' => $message,
                ],
            ],
```

and that attaches perfectly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was looking in the wrong place. The meta data is not attached to each payment but on the actual subscription itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using `subscription_data[metadata]` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-metadata)) as you've done is the way this is intended to work. Have you confirmed in your [request logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) that the metadata was included in your request as you expect? It's possible your `$message` might be empty in the subscription case.

If your Checkout session request did include the `subscription_data` `metadata` as expected, then you should also see this on the subscription object after the customer completes the Checkout session. Where are you looking at the resulting subscription which makes you conclude that it does not have `metadata`?

Comment: Even tried just hardcoding some values but same thing

Comment: what do you mean "same thing" where are you looking? What do you see?